# EPPlus Range Formula calculation takes forever on larger files

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I am working on a worksheet that contains around 87,000 rows and I am using a formula to add up purchase amounts that only belong to a certain invoice.

Here is my formula:

`workSheet.Cells[2, 17, workSheet.Dimension.End.Row, 17].Formula = "SUMIF(A:A,A"+2+",N:N)";`

And then I run an epplus range calculation so I can work with the values programmatically:

`workSheet.Cells[2, 17, workSheet.Dimension.End.Row, 17].Calculate();`

However, this .Calculate() takes a super long time to run. It works fine with smaller files! But once the data gets too big it increases the time complexity tremendously.

Is there anything I can do with the formula or EPPlus to have this .Calculate() execute quickly? Thanks!

Comment: Time is relative. What does: _.Calculate() takes a super long time to run_ mean? A month? A week? 4 hours? When trying to reduce that amount of time a task takes, it's important to work with quantifiable values. After you performed the operation multiple  times (ex: 5 times), what is the average amount of time that the operation takes? What does _quickly_ mean? What do you consider to be an acceptable amount of time?

Comment: @user9938 I figured it out. It was basically taking so long that I didn't feel like continue running the code. I have found out that the particular excel formula is O(n^2) because it recursively rechecks all the rows again for each row it passes when .calculate() is called within EPPlus, so I just had to make my own formula in C# that is O(n) time complexity which tremendously sped things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in comments:

> I have found out that the particular Excel formula is O(n^2) time complexity because it recursively rechecks all the rows again for each row it passes when `.calculate()` is called within EPPlus, so I just had to make my own formula in C# that basically does what the Excel formula is supposed to do, but this time it is O(n) time complexity which tremendously sped things up.